# What does class* mean when I am creating a CSS entry?

Tags: html, css

I have the following:

```
[class^="fa-icon-"], [class*=" fa-icon-"] {
```

I know that class^ means starts with but what does class* mean?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That simply means select any element whose `class` attribute contains a substring of `fa-icon-`

[**Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/V9ScV/)

So, as I've shared a demo with you, there am selecting any `p` element having a substring of `fa-icon-` (Note: The space matters there)

So it will select element say

```
<p class=" fa-icon-">Hello</p>
```

The above selector will also select something like

```
<p class=" fa-icon-blah">Hello</p>
```

[**Demo 2**](http://jsfiddle.net/V9ScV/2/)

Answer (score 1):

Represents an element with the class attribute whose value contains at least one instance of the substring " fa-icon-".

From the [w3c spec](http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-selectors/#attribute-substrings):

> [att*=val]
>
> Represents an element with the att attribute whose value contains at
>   least one instance of the substring "val". If "val" is the empty
>   string then the selector does not represent anything.

Comment: But is that not covered anyway with the class^ ?

Comment: No, because class^ only covers classes which **start** with that value (in your case fa-icon-)

Comment: Okay but the above is class*=" fa-icon-"  the space means it starts with.  Sorry to be confusing but do you see what I mean. I can't understand the point of the class* in this example.

Comment: Take a look at this fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/danield770/V9ScV/3/ I suspect the the intention of the class* is to match the class when other classes are also present.... (even though you would be better of using [att~=val] in that case)